# Why my map is only temporarily modfied in lambda function and value is not preserved?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I have local function, wherein am calling lambda function based on some conditions.
Lambda function should check if key exists in map. If no, add key with default value = 0; if yes, just incerement value.  When condition is satisfied lambda adds key to map, but only temporarily. Could you help me?

```
using center_points_t = std::unordered_map<potentialCircle, uint, potentialCircleHash, potentialCircleEqual>;
auto add_to_map = [&](center_points_t map, const int a, const int b, const int r){
    // if key does not exist, init with 0
    auto emplace_pair = map.emplace(potentialCircle(a, b, r), 0);
    // if exisiting key is added, increase counter and save as value
    emplace_pair.first->second += 1;
};

center_points_t calculate_center_points(){
    center_points_t center_points;
    center_points_t center_points_alternative = {{potentialCircle(1, 2, 3), 1}, { potentialCircle(1, 2, 4), 2 }};
    ...
    if(condition)
        add_to_map(center_points, a, b, combination.r_);
}
```

Comment: You are taking a copy of the map as argument, not the one you expect. If you replace `center_points_t map` with `center_points_t &map` it should work. Also, either the comment _if existing key is added_ or the code after it is wrong: you need to check the boolean member of `map::emplace` result to know if it was inserted. Example:
`if (emplace_pair.second) emplace_pair.first->second += 1;`. You can make that a bit more readable by using `std::tie`: `auto it = map.end(); bool inserted = false; std::tie(it, inserted) = map.emplace(...); if (inserted) it->second += 1;`

Comment: Then I don't understand how lambda works. :D :( thanks

Comment: That lambda doesn't need to capture anything. Did you expect the reference capture to apply to the arguments? Lambda parameters work exactly like other function parameters. (It's also not obvious why it's a lambda and not a plain function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jorge Bellon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5809597/jorge-bellon) says in comments. You have to replace `center_points_t map` by `center_points_t &map` then it should work. Because you are taking a copy of your variable but the `&` character send the address of the original variable instead of a copy to your lambda function.

So with `&map` your function will add a key to your original variable not to the copy as you want.